# GUI on Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, x11, graphical-user-interface

I have Amazon Linux AMI 2015.09 and i need to use some GUI application on it. When i tried to install desktop environment i found out that there are no any X11 packages on repos.

I tried to use CentOS repos but it's caused conflicts with pre instaled packages.

The way described in  [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=574740) topic is not work because there is no libX11* packages available.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Don't use Amazon Linux. Maybe it is good for Amazon but it is probably not good for anyone else!

Comment: I've already paid for it

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Bought reserved-instance for a year. Is it possible to change it's type from AMI Linux to CentOS?

Comment: Yes, you can run anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can compile all of those packages.

Or switch to a different OS and your problem goes away.

https://www.exratione.com/2014/08/do-not-use-amazon-linux/

Maybe this will help. According to these people, it will not be a problem to switch to a new OS.

https://www.quora.com/Can-I-change-AMIs-on-Amazon-EC2-reserved-instances